# Save an Arduino sketch on a progmem variable

Tags: memory-management, arduino, flash-memory, progmem

I want to save an Arduino sketch on a progmem variable, I thought about save it in  the form of strings but it's going to take a lot of space but then I thought about saving the hex instead. Do you have any idea about how doing this ? the syntax to use?

Comment: Do you want to save a whole sketch in PROGMEM? If so, what is the reason for this?

Comment: It's a way to update my program

Comment: Why place an update in PROGMEM when you can simply upload the 'up to date' code to begin with?

Comment: Because I thought everytime I would update I'll have to send my code via SPI to progmem  and then run it on my ATmega.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, when you upload a sketch it is stored in flash (progmem). I do not see what the problem is, or why you need to store an 'update'.

Comment: Because I want to update my code via Ethernet or Wifi for example everytime I will have to add features or fix bugs, so I want a simple way to that. Do you know a syntax to use to store the hex file in a progmem? or is it done automatically? because I don't want my code to end up in SRAM

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to do this. It would require replacing the bootloader with a custom code to allow writing to flash. You could look at using an ESP8266. Or use a second arduino to reprogram the first.

There are a few projects around that can turn an ESP8266 into a IP -> Serial tunnel which will allow uploading to the board as if it were plugged into the PC, but through a Wifi connection instead.

Comment: After considering the second option which is using a second Arduino, that plays the role "Arduino as ISP" , but how i'm gonna send the sketch if I want to update ( via Ethernet or Wifi) for example and where it's gonna go?